# Finding the top 5 sql and displaying them at the top ASC

Tags: sql

I want to find the TOP 5 hits from my users and displaying the TOP 5 at the beginning and then displaying the rest of the query following. Here is the code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
JOIN 
   (SELECT user_id, hits FROM user) T 
INNER JOIN 
   stats ON user.user_id = stats.user_id 
WHERE 
   user.online = 'Online' 
ORDER BY 
   user_id DESC
```

Basically I wanted to add to my `(SELECT user_id, hits FROM user)` a `TOP 5` count and displaying those `ASC` first on the output.

```
  SELECT TOP 5 hits 
  FROM users
```

When I try to add it that way it will not display any rows. How can I set my SQL right?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply just ORDER BY... then you will have Top 5 on top and other will be display based on the order?

```
SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN stats ON
user.user_id = stats.user_id WHERE user.online = 'Online' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN user.hits IN (SELECT TOP 5 user.hits FROM USERS ORDER BY user.hits) 
THEN user.hits ELSE user.id DESC
```

Comment: Edited the answer, may you tried it with your case ---- another thought, it can be done by get Top 5 and then merging with the others? --- so you don't have one complicated queries :D -